# What is the best way to avoid if-conditional inside of a loop?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ code that looks like this:

```
int A = 1;
int B = 1;
for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
    if(A==1) {
        doA();
    }
    if(B==1) {
        doB();
    }
    doC();
}
```

I know it hurts performance to place conditions inside a loop. It would be good to move these conditons out of it. However, if I do that I will have to rewrite the function 4 times here (for combinations of `A` and `B`).

What would be a good way to get the performance and write less code? Is using an empty function worth it, performance-wise? How should I duplicate a function that has the exact type of `doA()` but does nothing?

Comment: Is it really the bottleneck of your program?

Comment: Turn on optimizations, and look at the output assembly. A compiler might optimize that into three separate loops (unless A/B can change inside the loop)

Comment: Whats the point of `(A==1)` or `(B==1)` inside the loop if they are never changed?

Comment: Measure the performance of your code. Is it fast enough? Stop. Otherwise come back to SO with the real code.

Comment: Aside from the above comments, these types of cases will be handled well by "branch prediction" (lookup that term).

Comment: @CoryKramer Easily accessible by SO's top voted answer :)

Comment: ***Is it really the bottleneck of your program?*** It should not be. Your compiler and CPU are smart enough for this to not be a real problem especially if you are not looping millions of times. Provided branch prediction predicts correctly most of the time an if () can take effectively 1  (or some other small number) clock cycle on a CPU that operates at billions of clock cycles per second.

Comment: Unless your condition can change, don't bother refactoring the code.  Branch predictors will see you always or always don't take the branch and just do on like it was never there in the first place.  Also, the only way to **know** if the performance is hurt is to profile/benchmark the code and get real numbers.

Comment: ***I know it hurts performance to place condition inside a loop.*** Who ever told you that did not tell you the whole story.

Comment: If it's *fast enough* in an optimised build, don't worry about it.

Comment: If `doA` has the signature `void doA()`, then `void doNothing()` would have the correct signature.  You could use `auto maybeA = (A == 1) ? &doA : &doNothing;` before the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [How] to avoid if-conditional inside of a loop?

If none of the functions modify `A` or `B`, then you can move the condition to the outside of the loop:

```
if (A==1 && B==1) {
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        doA();
        doB();
        doC();
    }
} else if(A==1) {
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        doA();
        doC();
    }
} else if(B==1) {
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        doB();
        doC();
    }
} else {
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        doC();
    }
}
```

If the order of the function calls do not matter, then you can simplify:

```
if (A==1 && B==1) {
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        doA();
        doB();
    }
} else if(A==1) {
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        doA();
    }
} else if(B==1) {
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        doB();
    }
}
for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
    doC();
}
```

---

> I know it hurts performance to place condition inside a loop.

It can. On the other hand, it doesn't *necessarily* hurt performance at all. Hoisting of loop invariants is a fairly standard compiler optimisation. If the compiler thinks it is faster and can prove that it doesn't change the behaviour, then it may do the transformation automatically.

Even if the compiler does not do the optimisation, it is possible that the performance cost is insignificant.

> However, if I do that I will have to rewrite functions 4 times here (with combinations of calling function A/B).

This is true, and is a good argument to avoid manually hoisting the condition to the outside of the loop. On the other hand, the function is quite simple so there is not much to rewrite, as demonstrated.

> What would be a good way to get the performance ...

What you've written is probably good. You can compare measurements with the explicit hoisting and see if improves at all. If it does, then consider whether the improvement is worth the added complexity.

> What would be a good way to ... write fewer code?

What you've written is fairly optimal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case, A,B would be runtime-dependent but would not change inside the loop. Does branch prediction apply succussfully in this scenario? I still would like to avoid explicit hoisting. So I was thinking to use a function void doNothing() that has same type as void doA(); Do you thinks it is a good practice since there is overhead for the doNothing() function.

Comment: @Mira Branch predictors can be complex beasts, and general assumptions won't be accurate. If `doX`  are very simply and don't have any branches of their own, then the condition in the loop is probably predicted well. If the functions are complex and do have branches, then the loop isn't necessarily predicted well, but it also probably wouldn't matter since the runtime would presumably be dominated by the complex `doX` functions rather than the branches in the outer loop. I don't see an advantage in adding a call to function that does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I agree that the performance hurt is minimal. But I was also wondering if it helps with vectorization if removing the condition? I was constantly told that such condition would hurt SIMD optimization.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you think that your code is badly designed and you need to rewrite the code, from my experience it is best to simply rewrite the code.
Addressing the body of your question, if statements don't really hurt performance. Try fixing the algorithm instead, if you notice some issues.
A different aspect of the question is code complexity (how complex the code look). Switch case is (for the most part) easier on the eye.

I don't really understand the third part of your question, the part about empty functions. Explain more in the comments or edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the compiler can prove that the conditions are invariant over the loop, it should hoist them out of it with even moderate optimization. Even if it doesn't though, are you sure that's significant? Anyway, for more complex cases, especially if escape-analysis isn't that trivial, assigning them to a flag before the loop and then using that might give it the push needed.

Rarely should you hoist it yourself, but if you insist, lambdas are wonderful:

```
auto f = [&](auto a, auto b){
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        if constexpr (a)
            doA();
        if constexpr (b)
            doB();
        doC();
    }
};

if (A == 1 && B == 1)
    f(std::true_type(), std::true_type());
else if (A == 1)
    f(std::true_type(), std::false_type());
else if (B == 1)
    f(std::false_type(), std::true_type());
else
    f(std::false_type(), std::false_type());
```